# adding options to drop down box dynamically

Tags: html, combobox

I want to dynmically add some options to drop down box.but i want to mark one of them as selected .How can i do it?

```
DropdownBox = document.getElementById("xyzid");
 var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
 optn.text="txt";
 optn.value="value";
 DropdownBox.options.add("values");
```

the above code is executed inside loop with diff values .How can i mark one as selected?

Answer (score 0):

```
DropdownBox.options[0].selected = true;
```

Change the index as needed.

Update:

[HTML/JavaScript - Choose dropdown options using JavaScript](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial003.html)

Comment: What if i add 1 now , and 10 options later?,meaning will one option added first still be selected?

Comment: @akshay: whenever you need the selectedindex to change apply that.